# switch @model based on some logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Is it possible to switch @model based on some logic somehow?

i tried:

```
switch(somelogic){
    case "a" :
        @model Viewmodel
    case "b" :
        @model InputModel
    ....
}
```

but it does not like.

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Not AFAIK. That is the equivalent of changing a variable *type* (or a generic type argument) at runtime. I would (one of):

- write a common interface that the two models can implement
- write a wrapper model type with properties for the different options
- use `dynamic`
- use `object` and reflection

(in that order of preference, IMO)

Answer (score 1):

If you are supporting the same properties for both models (which would make sense as you are expressing expressions in a *declarative* fashion), why not either:

a. Have one model type inherit from another, e.g. `InputModel : ViewModel`, or;
b. Extract the shared properties as members of an interface, e.g. `IViewModel`, and simply declare `@model IViewModel`